# Fill between separately drawn random generated lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I want to illustrate that if a magnet is broken, the pieces keep being polar. I got stuck in trying to fill in the north pole of the upper piece since I don't know how to overcome the ragged lines that are randomly generated.

I'm very new to `TikZ` so pardon my efficiency, I drew it by hand first on a grid and used the coordinates to code it in `TikZ`. This is what I have got so far:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta, calc,fit,backgrounds,positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric, decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%\draw[step=0.5, gray, thin] (0,0) grid (9,6);
    

\draw[thick, black]
    (3.25,4)
    --(1,2.5)
    --(1,2)
    --(3,1.5)
    --(5.25,3)
    --(5.25,3.5)
    --(3,2)
    --(3,1.5)
    --(3,2)
    --(1,2.5)
    ;
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
    \draw[thick, decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}]
    (5.25,3.5) -- (3.25,4);

\draw[thick, black]
    (6.25,4.25)
    --(8.5,6)
    --(8.5,5.5)
    --(6.25,3.75)
    --cycle
    ;

\draw[thick, black]
    (8.5,6)
    --(6.5,6.5)
    --(4.25,4.75)
    --(4.25,4.25)
    ;
    
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\draw[thick, decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}]
    (6.25,3.75)--(4.25,4.25);
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\draw[thick, decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}]
    (6.25,4.25)--(4.25,4.75);

\draw[thick]
    (5.375,5.625)
    --(7.375,5.125)
    --(7.375,4.625)
    ;

\draw [thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red]
    (1,2.5)--(3,2)--(4.125,2.75)--(2.125,3.25);
\draw [thick,pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red]
    (1,2.5)--(3,2) -- (3,1.5) -- (1,2);
\draw [thick,pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red]
    (3,2)--(3,1.5)--(4.125,2.25)--(4.125,2.75);

%\draw [thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red];

\node (N) at (2.5,2.5){\textbf{{\large N}}};
\node (Z) at (3.75,3.45){\textbf{{\large Z}}};


\node (N) at (5.5,4.75){\textbf{{\large N}}};
\node (Z) at (7.25,6){\textbf{{\large Z}}};




\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be the easiest to use `spath3` and save the ragged line once and insert it – reversesd if needed – into the path. All those numbers make it hard to track where things are. Do you know there are libraries to help with 3d elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by @Qrrbrbirlbel answer (+1), but with use of `xslant` and `yslant` nodes, For exercise:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns.meta,  
                }
\begin{document}
  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dec/.style={
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetseed{42},
    decoration={random steps, segment length=10pt, amplitude=5pt}},
N/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, anchor=south west,
                        minimum height=5mm, minimum width=20mm, outer sep=0pt,
                        font=\huge\bfseries,
                        yslant=#1, xslant=#2},
P/.style args = {#1/#2}{pattern={Lines[angle=#1,distance={2pt},line width=0.1pt]},
                         pattern color=#2},
                       ]
\node (n1) [N=-0.5/ 0, P=90/red] {};
\node (n2) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/red] at (n1.south east) {};
\node (n3) [N= 0.5/-1, minimum size=20mm, P=0/red] at (n1.north east) {N};
\node (n4) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/blue] at (n2.south east) {};

\draw[P=0/blue] 
            (n3.south east) -- (n3.north east) 
                            -- ++ (2,1) decorate[dec] {-- (n4.north east)};
%
\node (n5) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/red] at ($(1,0.5) + (n4.south east)$) {};
\node (n6) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/blue] at (n5.south east) {};
\node (n7) [N= 0.5/-1, minimum size=20mm, P=0/blue] at (n5.north east) {S};

\draw[P=90/red]
            (n7.south west) -- (n7.north west) 
                            -- ++ (-2,-1)   coordinate (aux)
                            -- ++ ( 0,-0.5) decorate[dec] {-- (n5.south west)}
                            -- (n5.north west)
                            ;
\draw       (aux) decorate[dec] {-- (n5.north west)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
In above solution the pattern between random lines is the same as in above node. This I done because in the first try pattern protrude out of above/below drawn shape.

Meanwhile I discover what I did wrong. IN MWE below this is now corrected. For simpler define coordinates of random lines are now introduced two invisible nodes, which corners define coordinates for those lines:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns.meta,
                }
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dec/.style={
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetseed{42},
    decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}},
N/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, anchor=south west,
                        minimum height=5mm, minimum width=20mm, outer sep=0pt,
                        font=\huge\bfseries,
                        yslant=#1, xslant=#2},
P/.style args = {#1/#2}{pattern={Lines[angle=#1,distance={2pt},line width=0.1pt]},
                         pattern color=#2},
                       ]
\node (n1) [N=-0.5/ 0, P=90/red] {};
\node (n2) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/red] at (n1.south east) {};
\node (n3) [N= 0.5/-1, minimum size=20mm, P=0/red] at (n1.north east) {N};
\node (n4) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/blue] at (n2.south east) {};
\node (n5) [N= 0.5/-1, minimum size=20mm, draw=none] at (n3.south east) {};
\draw[P=0/blue]
            (n5.north east) decorate[dec] {-- (n5.south east)}
                         -- (n5.south west) -- (n5.north west)
                         -- cycle;

\node (n6) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/red] at ($(1,0.5) + (n4.south east)$) {};
\node (n7) [N= 0.5/ 0, P=90/blue] at (n6.south east) {};
\node (n8) [N= 0.5/-1, minimum size=20mm, P=0/blue] at (n6.north east) {S};
\node (n9) [N= 0.5/-1, draw=none,
            minimum size=20mm] at (n6.north west) {};
\draw[P=0/red]
    (n9.south west) -- (n9.south east) -- (n9.north east) -- (n9.north west)
        decorate[dec] {-- (n9.south west)} 
    ;
\node (n10) [N=-0.5/ 0, draw=none, anchor=south east] at (n6.south west) {};
%
\draw[P=90/red,
      line cap=round, line join=round]
    (n10.south west) -- (n10.north west)
        decorate[dec] {-- (n10.north east)}
    (n10.south west)        
        decorate[dec] {-- (n10.south east)}
                    -- (n10.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can decorate only a part of a line, say

```
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) decorate {-- (1,1)} -- (0,1) -- cycle;
```

to have a rectangle with a ragged line on only one side and with a fixed seed this would be reproducable. And you can do this even twice on separate segments of the path like so

```
\tikz[
  dec/.style={
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetseed{42},
    decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}}]
  \draw[fill=gray, ultra thick, line cap=round, line join=round]
             (0,0) decorate[dec] {-- (1,0)}
    (0,0) -- (0,1) decorate[dec] {-- (1,1)} -- (1,0);
```

which gives a relative good looking rectangle but only because in has round caps and joins:
[image]

---

While TikZ provides a way to save a path and reuse it later it can't be inserted in a path that is getting constructed. This is where the `spath3` library comes in.

With `spath/save` we can save the ragged line once. And with `spath/insert` we can insert that segment at the current point in the path and with `spath/insert reverse` the segment gets reversed before it gets inserted.

This allows a normal closed path.

---

In the code below I've used the 3d capabilities of TikZ with the `3d` library that offers canvases in various planes.

Since the canvas key aren't really saying much I'm using styles like

- `top face`,
- `side face` and
- `front face` with an optional argument so that we have easy access to the front face of the broken North piece.

In addition to that, I'm using PGFMath functions (four of them are constants) to be able

1. to use speaking names (width, depth and height are things I can visualize better) and
2. to not have to repeat numbers which also allows us to change the size of the broken magnet by just adjusting one value and not dozens of them.

The side faces can easily be drawn in a `\foreach` loop because `depthOfPiece(<piece>)` gets us the depth of that piece (starting with 0) which already includes the space between the break automatically.

Since all these canvases and the swapping around of *x* and *y* values are sometimes a bit confusing (especially when width and depth have the same value) I've added a “debug loop” that shows all main canvases and the direction of their axes.

---

Excuse the horrible pattern in the output picture, Image Magick does a bad job converting the pattern.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  3d,
  spath3,
  patterns.meta,
  decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dec/.style={
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetseed{42},
    decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}},
  line join=round,
  % the pattern
  /pgf/pattern keys/every pattern/.style={distance=1.5pt},
  north/.style ={pattern color=red,  pattern={Lines[every pattern,angle= 90]}},
  north'/.style={pattern color=red,  pattern={Lines[every pattern,angle=-45]}},
  south/.style ={pattern color=blue, pattern={Lines[every pattern,angle= 90]}},
  south'/.style={pattern color=blue, pattern={Lines[every pattern,angle=-45]}},
  % 3d stuff
  front face/.style={canvas is yz plane at x={depthOfPiece(#1)}},
  front face/.default=0,
  side face/.style ={canvas is xz plane at y=0},
  top face/.style  ={canvas is xy plane at z=Height},
  x=(35:.75cm), y=(160:1cm), z=(90:.5cm),
  % geometry
  declare function={
    Height = 1;   % z direction
    Width  = 2;   % y direction
    Depth  = 2;   % x direction
    dDepth = 1.3; % distance between broken pieces
    depthOfPiece(\x) = % evals x value for piece's closest corner to viewer
      \x * Depth + (\x >= 2) * dDepth;}
  ]
% create the ragged line and save it
\path[dec,decorate] (0,0,0) -- (0, Width, 0) [spath/save=ragged line];

% front face
\draw[front face, north] (0,0) rectangle +(Width, Height);

% side pieces
\foreach[count=\piece from 0] \style in {north, south, north, south}
  \draw[side face, \style]
    (depthOfPiece \piece, 0) rectangle +(Depth, Height);

% top face
\begin{scope}[top face, transform shape, font=\Huge\bfseries]
  % the unbroken ones are easy
  \foreach \piece/\style/\text in {0/north'/N, 3/south'/Z}
    \draw[\style] (depthOfPiece \piece,0) rectangle
      node {\text} +(Depth, Width);
  
  % the broken ones are not
  % could be made with \foreach and a complex variable path
  \draw[south'] (depthOfPiece 1,0) -- +(right:Depth)
       [spath/append=ragged line]  -| cycle
   node at (depthOfPiece 1.5,.5*Width) {Z};
  \draw[north'] (depthOfPiece 2,0) [spath/append=ragged line]
        -- + (right:Depth) |- cycle
   node at (depthOfPiece 2.5,.5*Width) {N};
\end{scope}

% the broken front face
% this is where spath3 is necessary because the inverse is needed
\draw[front face=2, north]
  (0,0) [spath/append=ragged line] -- ++(up: Height)
        [spath/append reverse=ragged line] -- cycle;

% debug faces
\foreach \face/\col in {front/red, side/green, top/blue}
  \draw[ultra thick, transform shape, <->, \face\space face=4,
    \col, font=\Huge, nodes={fill=white, draw}]
    (0,3) node[above]{$y$} |- (3,0) node[right]{$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz[
  dec/.style={
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetseed{42},
    decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}}]
\matrix[column sep=5mm, ultra thick, every path/.append style={fill=gray}]{
  \draw      (0,0) decorate[dec] {-- (1,0)}
    (0,0) -- (0,1) decorate[dec] {-- (1,1)} -- (1,0);
  &
  \draw[line cap=round, line join=round]
             (0,0) decorate[dec] {-- (1,0)}
    (0,0) -- (0,1) decorate[dec] {-- (1,1)} -- (1,0);\\};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: The `/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetseed{42}` is a brilliant idea!

Comment: MIssing in the figure North and Z? Z what is? +1

Comment: @Sebastiano I've updated my answer with more comments and removed the hard-coded numbers. I've added the letters for North and Zuiden (the Dutch word for South).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Now I have understood. :-). On the z-axis there written "y". Good LaTeX.

Answer (score 8):

There is a probably a much better way to do this, but you could "overfill" the front edge of the magnet (so that the jagged edge will be covered no matter how exactly the line goes) and then cover it up when you draw the top site:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, patterns.meta, calc,fit,backgrounds,positioning,arrows,shapes.geometric, decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%\draw[step=0.5, gray, thin] (0,0) grid (9,6);
    

\draw[thick, black]
    (3.25,4)
    --(1,2.5)
    --(1,2)
    --(3,1.5)
    --(5.25,3)
    --(5.25,3.5)
    --(3,2)
    --(3,1.5)
    --(3,2)
    --(1,2.5)
    ;
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
    \draw[thick, decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}]
    (5.25,3.5) -- (3.25,4);

\draw[thick, black]
    (6.25,4.25)
    --(8.5,6)
    --(8.5,5.5)
    --(6.25,3.75)
    --cycle
    ;

\draw[thick, black]
    (8.5,6)
    --(6.5,6.5)
    --(4.25,4.75)
    --(4.25,4.25)
    ;
    
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\draw[thick,pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red]
    decorate[decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}] {(6.25,3.75)  -- (4.25,4.25)} -- (4.25,4.75) -- (6.25,5.25) -- (6.25,3.75);
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\draw[thick,fill=white]
   decorate[decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}] { (6.25,4.25)--(4.25,4.75)} --
    (5.375,5.625)
    --(7.375,5.125);
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\draw[thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red]
   decorate[decoration={random steps,segment length=10pt,amplitude=5pt}] { (6.25,4.25)--(4.25,4.75)} --
    (5.375,5.625)
    --(7.375,5.125);
    
\draw[thick,pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red] (7.375,5.125)--(6.25,4.25) -- (6.25,3.75) -- (7.375,4.625) -- cycle;

\draw[thick]
    (5.375,5.625)
    --(7.375,5.125)
    --(7.375,4.625)
    ;

\draw [thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red]
    (1,2.5)--(3,2)--(4.125,2.75)--(2.125,3.25);
\draw [thick,pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red]
    (1,2.5)--(3,2) -- (3,1.5) -- (1,2);
\draw [thick,pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red]
    (3,2)--(3,1.5)--(4.125,2.25)--(4.125,2.75);

%\draw [thick,pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red];

\node (N) at (2.5,2.5){\textbf{{\large N}}};
\node (Z) at (3.75,3.45){\textbf{{\large Z}}};


\node (N) at (5.5,4.75){\textbf{{\large N}}};
\node (Z) at (7.25,6){\textbf{{\large Z}}};




\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here does Ti*k*Z automatically generates the polygonal lines?

Comment: @youthdoo I'm not sure I understand your comment

Comment: @youthdoo Do you mean the random lines?

Comment: Yes, the random lines.

Comment: @youthdoo Yes, they are generated by TikZ. Both edges look the same because the user specified a random seed.